# call Model function from View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an HTML select in View, for the select options i have to retrieve value from database.   I have a function in model that returns LIST of options. How can I call the model's function from view.

Comment: You should not call model methods in your view, your controller should take care of giving the View a complete Model.

Comment: Don't put functions in your model and don't call functions in a view.  That's what controllers are for

Comment: So, how do I give options to HTML select from database?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public class XXXXViewModel {
    //properties...

    public List<Option> Options {get;set;}
}
```

and in your controller:

```
public class XXXXController : Controller {
    public ActionResult SomeAction(){
        var model = GetModelFromRepository();
        var viewModel = new XXXXViewModel{
                                            //Properties...
                                            Options = model.GetOptions();
                                         };
        return View(viewModel); 
    }
 }
```

So, you controller takes care of providing the options to the view using a ViewModel class containing everything your view needs.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

create an event which is going to call that function and by the help of json and Ajax javascript you can easily do it

its a small concept that model canot be call from html after rendering on client side you have to take care of it by controller action and ajax is a good practice for it in maximum of mvc application